# If $n$ is odd, then the set of $n$-cycles consists of two conjugacy classes of equal size in $A_n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

> If $n$ is odd, then the set of $n$-cycles consists of two conjugacy classes of equal size in $A_n$.

I have read [split conjugacy class in $S_n$ into two equal size conjugacy classes in $A_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2289000), but I still cannot clearly figure out why. I want to know how to begin the proof.

When I saw this problem, I first thought of the split criterion, but I don't know how to do next.

Could you tell me how you think through this problem and the proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

The centralizer of an $n$-cycle has cardinality $n$ and equals the subgroup generated by it. Therefore, the conjugacy class of an $n$-cycle in $A_n$ has cardinality $\frac{(n-1)!}{2}$. Now, we have $(n-1)!$ $n$-cycles.

Comment: I understand that the conjugacy class of an $n$-cycle in $A_n$ has cardinality ($n$−1)!2, but I'm not sure why we should multiply 2. I know that any $n$-cycle does not commute with an odd permutation and thus the conjugacy class splits. Do we have (n−1)!2 or (n-1)! in total?